# How to capture a subset of a Latex document?

Tags: comments, tags

I would like to programmatically capture a subset of a latex document, something like:

```
doc = new Doc("foo.tex")
node = doc.getNode("bar")
print node.text
```

where node `"bar"` would be delimited by some tags, put for example in comments:

```
%% <bar>
This the \textbf{node content}
%% </bar>
```

How to do this?

Comment: This is not really a TeX question but depends on the programming language you want to use as well as on the external tools. There are many ways for opening a text file and selecting a substring.

Comment: I agree, but TeX files have many specificities to be leveraged to do this elegantly and efficiently.

Comment: In a Unix environment nothing is simpler than an `awk` one-liner that removes everything outside of the tags. But whether this is adequate depends on the environment in which you want to use it. Using LaTeX to extract the fragments is certainly an overkill since you need a TeX installation for that. But let's see whether someone comes up with a TeX solution to the problem; I wouldn't hold my breath, though.

Comment: May be https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clipboard ?

Comment: clipboard looks very much appropriate, thanks a lot. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good job for the `catchfilebetweentags` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{input.tex}
not this text

%<*bar>
This the \textbf{node content}
%</bar>

not this text either
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}

\ExecuteMetaData[input.tex]{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are new paragraphs allowed within the tag?

Comment: @Sigur If they are explicitly given with `\par` they will work, empty lines are allowed, just will not have an effect.