# How to input multi parts of a file

Tags: input, loops, external-files

I have a .tex document(external.tex, for example) whose content is like this:

```
...
...
%*#<start>
some code
%*#<end>
...
...
%*#<start>
some other code
%*#<end>
...
...
```

I want to input all the parts wrapped between a pair of `%*#<start ... %*#<end>` of this file to my main doc. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\inputmultiparts{external.tex}
\begin{document}
% using code from "external.tex"
\end{document}
```

Comment: The syntax looks somewhat-similar to docstrip...

Comment: Would be duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343024/how-to-capture-a-subset-of-a-latex-document , if you don't mind changing the tag format a bit. I don't use the package myself so it might already work with the current format with some modifications

Comment: `catchfilebetweentags` package can only treat(find) the first pair of dilimiter tags it finds. In my example, there maybe many such tags which all need to be input to the main document.

Comment: May be possible with some packages which provide interfaces to read in from a file line by line, in verbatim. For example, using a customed `\verbatim@addtoline` with `verbatim` package.

Comment: Well *of course* it's possible with sufficiently amount of programming. (another drawback is lost synctex ability, however.)

Comment: Might solve your question: [macros - Import several parts of file at once - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297389/import-several-parts-of-file-at-once)

Comment: Depending on your use case (does the code in `external.tex` change often? where does it come from? which operating system do you use? is it just for you or also for other people?) it may be easier to process the file with grep or awk or perl etc., either fully separated from the LaTeX compilation or with a system call from within your document.

Comment: @Marijn Yes. my `external.tex` changes often. It collects many macros that are for me in my `Windows` system.

Comment: @user202729 Thank you for the solution you provided( macros - Import several parts of file at once). This solution needs to open/search/close file several times depending on to the quality of `tags`. It would cost a lot if there are many different `tags` in the file. I wonder if there is method to extract all parts between pairs of tags with same name.